# How to automatically infer the row type information for a given query

Tags: apache-flink

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.RowTypeInfo
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation

var fieldTypes: Array[TypeInformation[_]] = Array(createTypeInformation[String],createTypeInformation[String],createTypeInformation[String])

var fieldNames: Array[String] = Array("UUID", "Name","instanceid")

val rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo( fieldTypes,  fieldNames )

val inputFormat = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat().setDrivername("com.vertica.jdbc.Driver").setDBUrl("jdbc:vertica://x.x.x.x:5433/hfdb").setUsername("user").setPassword("password").setQuery("select * from test").setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo).finish()

val dataset = benv.createInput(inputFormat)

dataset.print()
```

So in the above code we have to specify the type of the rows which we are getting . is there a way to get the answer without setting row type ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. 
`JDBCInputFormat` requires you to specify the result type.

Comment: i got workaround . i used prepared statement to get metadata of the columns which give column types and column name .

Comment: @NaveenHolla, any chance you can share your solution?